# How to share host network bridge when using docker in docker

Tags: docker

I'm using the https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind docker image to have docker in docker. When starting docker containers inside the parent docker, is it possible to use the bridge of the parent docker so I can share the network between the containers inside the docker container and the parent docker container?

What I want to do is to access the containers inside the parent docker container from the host directly by IP to assign domain names to them.

UPDATE -> Main Idea

I'm upgrading a free online Java compiler to allow users to run any program using docker. So I'm using the dind (docker in docker image) to launch a main container that have inside a Java program that receive requests and launch docker containers inside of it. 
So what I want to do is to give the users the option to run programs that expose a port and let them access their containers using a subdomain.
So graphically I have this hierarchy

```
Internet -> My Host -> Main Docker Container -> User Docker Container 1
                                             -> User Docker Container 2
                                             -> User Docker Container n
```

And what I want to do is to give the user a subdomain name to access his "User Docker Container" for example: www.user_25.compiler1.browxy.com

So he can have a program that expose a port in his "User Docker Container" and can access it using the subdomain www.user_25.compiler1.browxy.com

What confuses me is that to access the "User Docker Container" I need to access before the Main Docker Container. I'm trying to find a way to access the "User Docker Container" directly, so I thought that if the User Docker Container and the Main Docker container can share the same network I can access the User Docker Container directly from the host and assign a domain name to the "User Docker Container" IP updating the /etc/hosts file on the host.

Thanks a lot for any advice or suggestion :)

Comment: What if you were to start dind container in `--net=host` mode?

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks for the suggestion, but I think I need different IP addresses for each container due that the objective I'd like to achieve is to access a service on a port in the inner containers using a subdomain. So if I use --net-host I can have port clashing I think. But maybe there is something that I'm not understanding and this is the solution

Comment: Can you update your question to show a *specific example* of what you want to work?  I'm not entirely clear, and rather than trying to describe it here in the comments it would be better to update the question.

Comment: Thanks larsks, yes you are right. I updated the main question with a concrete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I took many ideas that larsks gave me and this is what I did

1. Start docker in docker container with a name (--name compiler)
2. Execute this command in the host -> sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 gw `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' compiler` netmask 255.255.255.0

For this to work I added a custom bridge in the docker in docker container that ensure that the ip range is 10.0.0.0/24

Now I can ping containers created inside the docker in docker container from the host

To have name resolution I installed docker-dns as larsks suggested into the docker in docker container and added the IP of it to /etc/resolv.conf in the host

The result is that from the host I can access containers by name that are created inside the docker in docker container.

One possible updgrade thing that I'd like to have is to configure everything with docker and don't add custom stuff into the host but by now I don't know how to do that and I can live with this solution

Answer (score 0):

If you run your "Main docker container" with `--net=host`, then your configuration simplifies to:

```
Internet -> Host -> User Docker Container 1
                 -> User Docker Container 2
                 -> User Docker Container n
```

Although you probably want to use a bridge other than `docker0` for the child containers (e.g., create a new bridge `docker1`, and start your dind Docker daemon with `-b docker1`).

If two users were to attempt to publish a service on the same port at the same ip address, then yes, you would have port conflicts.  There are a few ways of working around this:

1. If you can support multiple public ip addresses on your host, then you can "assign" (in quotes because this would not be automatic) one to each container.  Instead of running `docker run -p 80:80 ...`, you would need to make the bind ip explicit, like `docker run -p 80:80:1.2.3.4`.  This requires people to "play nice"; that is, there is nothing to prevent someone from either forgetting to specify a bind address or from specifying the wrong address.
2. If you are explicitly running *web* services, then you may be able to use some sort of front-end proxy to map subdomain names to containers using name-based virtual host.  There are several components to this process, and making it *automated* would probably require a little work.  Doing it manually is comparatively easy (just update `/etc/hosts`, for example), but is fragile because when a container is restarted it will have a new ip address.  Something like [a dynamic dns service](https://hub.docker.com/r/phensley/docker-dns/) can help with this.

These are mostly suggestions more than solutions, but let me know if you would like more details.  There are probably other ways of cracking this particular nut, so hopefully someone else will chime in.

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks!! About 1) Very nice solution, the problem is that I'd like the process to be automatic to don't worry about IP addressing. About 2) I didn't know about that dynamic dns service, this will solve part of the problem Thanks! One additional info is that the java program that is running on the main docker container is listening to docker events and I can do whatever I like when I receive an event (maybe I can use that for something). Other option I was looking at is to add a network routes (but I'm not a netwoking guru) and I don't know if it's applicable in this case